# Repeating analysis over categories with lapply or plyr

Tags: r

I've got myself stuck doing something I thought would be simple - subset a data frame then print some output from a couple of tests, repeated over categories

In the spirit of avoiding for loops I've tried lapply but it seems to be overwriting the oneway with the anova

I've also tried dlply, which doesn't run.

```
library(plyr)

dat<-data.frame(value=rnorm(300),
                    aCategory=rep(1:3, c(100, 100, 100)),
                    bCategory=rep(1:2, 300)
                    )

aFunc<-function(cat){
  sub<-subset(dat, aCategory=="cat")
  oneway.test(value~bCategory, dat)
  summary(aov(value~bCategory, dat))
}

lapply(unique(dat$aCategory), aFunc)

dlply(dat, .(aCategory), summarise, 
      oneway.test(value~bCategory),
      summary(aov(value~bCategory))
      )
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You probably shouldn't do repeated one-way anovas, but a two-way anova instead,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can only have one return value. Try this:

```
aFunc<-function(cat){
  #sub<-subset(dat, aCategory==cat)
  #help(subset) warns against using subset inside functions
  sub <- dat[dat$aCategory==cat,]
  list(oneway.test(value~bCategory, sub),
       summary(aov(value~bCategory, sub)))
}

lapply(unique(dat$aCategory), aFunc)
```

Here I had to correct some more mistakes, e.g. actually do the tests with the subset and compare with the value of `cat` and not with the string `"cat"`.

Note that `lapply` is still a loop.

Comment: Apologies for the errors in the code, I should have checked those.  Thank you very much for you help, that does the job.  Useful to know about subsetting within functions too - I hadn't spotted that